# if na tela antes da consulta ser realizada

Tags: php, libcurl

Estou tentando criar um consultor com PHP que faz uma requisição em um formulário com um e-mail do cliente e me retorna se ele é cadastrado no serviço. O problema é que quando inicio minha página diretamente o `if` me imprime na tela o valor `true` (ele só deve me passa os valores do `if` depois da consulta feita).

Código HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

        <!-- Optional theme -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">

        <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<head>
</head>
<head>

    <title>.::Cliente Consultor::.</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="POST">
<center>
    <BR>
        <BR>
            <BR>
<font size="4" color="orange" face="Segoe Print">.::Consulta::.<img src=""  </font></span></p></div align=""> 
<BR>
    <BR>
        <BR>
<input type="text" name="bin">
<input type="submit">
</center>   
</form>
</body>
<style>
body { 
  background: url() no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  color: black;
}
.twitter a{
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif  ;
  font-size: 50px;
  text-shadow: grey 0px 0px 10px;
}


}</style>
</html>
```

Código PHP:

```
<?php


 error_reporting(0);

$bin = $_POST['bin'];

            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://minhaconta.payleven.com.br/forgot-password");
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

           curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "password_token_type[email]=$bin" );
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
            $s = curl_exec($ch);

$mensagem = ' ';


if ($1 == $2) 

{



            $q = explode('</title>', $s);  
            $1 = $q[1];
            $2 = $q[1];
            $binchecker = " [".$bin."] ";

$mensagem = 'cliente encontrado';

} 

else

{

$mensagem= 'cliente não cadastrado';

}


   echo "<br><br><center>".$mensagem."</center>";




?>
```

Comment: O código PHP está no mesmo arquivo que o HTML? E você não deveria executar a verificação somente quando o formulário for submetido? Então falta um `if` validando a requisição. Quem são `$1` e `$2` e o que deveria fazer `if ($1 == $2)`? Leia sobre as [regras de nomenclatura de variáveis do PHP](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.variables.basics.php).

Comment: Todo o codigo está em um unico arquivo index.php as variaveis $1 e $2 contem o conteudo do explode  que armazena o html da pagina em que foi feita a requisição, o if compara os dois e me retorna true ou false

Comment: Praticamente quero checar se um email e cadastrado neste site e me retornar o email com a resposta ao lado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Para executar um código PHP apenas quando o formulário é submetido, você precisa fazer uma verificação do método HTTP da requisição tratada e os campos presentes nessa requisição.

   ```
   <?php

   if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
       // Código aqui...
   }
   ```
2. Não utilize `error_reporting(0)` sem saber o que está fazendo. Ao meu ver, você jamais deveria utilizar esta linha de código. Isso ocultará qualquer mensagem de erro no seu código, mas as mensagens de erro são suas melhores amigas.
3. O PHP não permite variáveis com nomes iniciando com números, apenas com letra ou sublinhado. Leia a [documentação](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.variables.basics.php) para mais detalhes.
4. Não faz sentido você verificar o valor de duas variáveis antes de definí-la. Você está definindo o valor de `$1` e `$2` apenas dentro do `if`, então na condição `$1 == $2` nenhuma das duas existe.

> Lembrando que `$1` e `$2` não são nomes válidos para variáveis.

5. Também não faz sentido você fazer o `echo` de um elemento HTML fora da tag `html` e `body`. A mensagem deveria ser devidamente exibida no corpo da página.

Comment: Obrigado me ajudou muito, meu codigo está funcionando perfeitamente